# How to make XHR requests in functional intern tests

Tags: iis-7, dojo, intern

I have an app that I have developed using localhost. It makes relative xhr requests like this

```
http://localhost/arcgis/rest/...
```

When I try to run the app from within a functional test using intern, it loads my app on port 9000 (`http://localhost:9000/...`). This is causing all of my xhr requests to fail because they are now cross-domain.

I could probably make it work using jsonp or CORS, but I'm wondering if intern has already solved this problem. It would be great if it had a proxy that made the requests using a configurable base url or something. Is this functionality available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intern AJAX Unit Tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739642/intern-ajax-unit-tests)

Answer (score 1):

It's all spelled out in the new wiki page: [Using Intern to unit test Ajax calls](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-Intern-to-unit-test-Ajax-calls).

Thanks, Colin!