# Intern ajax testing with node.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, intern

I'm using intern with node.js, trying to set up intern for ajax testing. The server code below serves direct GET requests, but XHR request by Intern doesn't seem to reach to it. I suspect the problem is something to do with proxyUrl setup for the Node.

server/main.js: Node/express

```
...

app.get('/data', function(request, response, next){
if(request.xhr)
{
    var data = dfs.readFileSync("src/server/data.json");
    response.render(data, {
        root: root,
        error: new Error('Cant read file')
});
}
else
    next();
});

...

app.listen(8001);

http_proxy.createServer(function(req,res, proxy){
    proxy.proxyRequest(req,res, {host:'localhost', port:8001});
}).listen(9000);
```

intern.hello.js: (unit test code)

```
...

'async test': function () {
    var dfd = this.async(1000);

    request('/data').then(dfd.callback(function (data) {
        assert.strictEqual(data, 'hello world');
    }, dfd.reject.bind(dfd)));
}
```

intern config:

```
...
proxyPort:9000,
proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:8001/',
...
```

intern error:

```
Warning: FAIL: async test (1015ms)
Error: Timeout reached on main - wait - async test
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at new ErrorCtor (.../node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/errors/create.js:13:21)
    at null._onTimeout (.../node_modules/intern/lib/Test.js:164:21)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
2/3 tests passed
2/3 tests passed Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intern AJAX Unit Tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739642/intern-ajax-unit-tests)

Comment: `proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',` ??

Comment: here is how I worked this issue: 1. In nginx.conf, I added: `location=/data { proxy_pass http://locahost:8900/;` while `location / {proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;`. My Node app is running on 8001 and I'm creating a proxy on 8900, as below, 2. In my Node app, I created a proxy server: `http_proxy.createServer(8900, 'localhost').listen(9000);  http.createServer(function (req, res) {  // custom logic here  }).listen(8900);` while my Node app creates/listens to its server at 8001 at the same time.  That's it. Changing Intern's proxyPort/proxyUrl parameters had no effect.